# Difficulty adding slug to Generic Detail View in Django

Tags: django, primary-key, django-urls, slug

The view works with just the PK, however, the problem is that my PK on the live site is an incoherent string and I want to make it coherent titling for an article to boost SEO. I don't want to change the PK to the slug. I want both.

When I try to add both the PK and a slug it fails and I get the error: no reverse match.

URL path:

```
 path('idea/<slug:slug>,<int:pk>', views.IdeaDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

Model:

```
class Idea(models.Model):
    idea_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Searches ID')
    idea_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    idea_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    idea_text = NonStrippingTextField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
```

Views.py:

```
class IdeaDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Idea
    template_name = "idea/detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IdeaDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['results'] = Idea.objects.filter(idea_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return context
```

Admin.py:

```
class IdeaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("idea_title",)}
```

I want to add a slug which is the idea_title, however if I try to add that into the URL it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slugfield, get_absolute_url method, and save method to your Idea model, like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Idea(models.Model):
        idea_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Searches ID')
        idea_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        idea_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
        idea_text = NonStrippingTextField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(
            default='',
            editable=False,
            max_length=300,
        )

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            kwargs = {
                'pk': self.id,
                'slug': self.slug
            }
            return reverse('idea-pk-slug-detail', kwargs=kwargs)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            value = self.title
            self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, in urls.py:

```
path('idea/<int:pk>-<str:slug>/', views.IdeaDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

And, in views.py right under template_name:

```
query_pk_and_slug = True
```

Two more methods and more info found [HERE](https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/generating-slugs-automatically-in-django-easy-solid-approaches/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is a great answer, for some reason it's still not working in that the model cannot find the pk.